# Is there a tool to import a sprite sheet into Flash as a frame-based animation?

Tags: flash, animation, spritesheet

I'm looking for a tool that can help create a Flash-based animation given a spritesheet -- basically the reverse of [Spriteloq](http://www.loqheart.com/spriteloq/).

I'd like to take a sheet like the one below, import it into Flash, and then use Spriteloq (or a similar tool) to re-export as an optimized sheet that is compatible with the game engine I'd like to use -- instead of creating software that can read the specific sheet.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look into either [FlashPunk](http://www.flashpunk.net) or [Flixel](http://flixel.org/). They are bitmap-based (as opposed to vector-based) game libraries in ActionScript 3 that support importing image files like yours as animated sprites.